# How to Remap Array of Objects when State gets updated in React JS?

Tags: reactjs, react-beautiful-dnd

I am a newbie trying to mess around React, I cam across a problem on which I have been stuck for like 2 days is that I have an Array (state array to be precise) in which I add values by SetArray method, all works fine and nice, however I am also assigning that Array values to another array and mapping the second array. Now the problem is the first array gets updated everywhere the second in which I assign values from first one doesn't render immediately, it renders only when the whole section gets rendered.

**Setting Values in Array 1 on Click (is has complicated OnClick function as well, haven't added here, this works fine btw)**

```
const [globalFLZ, setGlobalFLZ] = useState([]);
const addGlobalFLZ = (obj) => {
    const idd = 1;
    const newGlobalFLZ = { idd, ...obj };
    setGlobalFLZ([...globalFLZ, newGlobalFLZ]);
}
```

**Assigning values from Array 1 in Array 2**

```
const weekColumns = {
    [uuid()]: {
        name: "All Items",
        items: globalFLZ              // assigning here
    },
    [uuid()]: {
        name: "Week 1",
        items: []
    },
    [uuid()]: {
        name: "Week 2",
        items: []
    },
    [uuid()]: {
        name: "Week 3",
        items: []
    },
    [uuid()]: {
        name: "Week 4",
        items: []
    },
    [uuid()]: {
        name: "Week 6",
            items: []
    }
};
```

**Code to Map Array 2**

As this is nested array, first **columns** get mapped then **items** inside it

```
{Object.entries(columns).map(([columnId, column], index) => {
    return (
        <Box
            boxShadow={1}
            key={columnId}
            className="diDragableColumn"
        >
                <Box className="diDragableColumnTitle" boxShadow={1}><h3>{column.name}</h3></Box>

                <Droppable droppableId={columnId} key={columnId} direction="vertical">
                    {(provided, snapshot) => {
                        return (
                            <div
                                {...provided.droppableProps}
                                ref={provided.innerRef}
                                style={{
                                    background: snapshot.isDraggingOver
                                        ? "lightgrey"
                                        : "",
                                    minHeight: '100%',
                                }}
                                className="diDropable"
                            >
                                {column.items.map((item, index) => {   // the problem is here
                                    return (
                                        <Draggable
                                            key={item.id}
                                            draggableId={`dragID`+item.id}
                                            index={index}
                                        >
                                            {(provided, snapshot) => {
                                                return (
                                                    <Tooltip 
                                                        title={item.answerAusformuliert}
                                                        arrow 
                                                        placement="top" 
                                                        className="di-tooltip"
                                                        classes={{
                                                            tooltip: classes.tooltip,
                                                            arrow: classes.arrow
                                                        }} 
                                                    >
                                                        <div
                                                            ref={provided.innerRef}
                                                            {...provided.draggableProps}
                                                            {...provided.dragHandleProps}
                                                            style={{
                                                                margin: "0 7px 7px 0",
                                                              ...provided.draggableProps.style
                                                            }}
                                                            className="diDraggableItem"
                                                        >

                                                            {item.answerAusformuliert}
                                                            {item.id}
                                                            
                                                            
                                                        </div>
                                                        </Tooltip>
                                                );
                                            }}
                                        </Draggable>
                                    );
                                })}
                                {provided.placeholder}
                            </div>
                        );
                    }}
                </Droppable>
            </Box>
    );
})}
```

Required: ***column.items.map*** should automatically re-map as Array 1 gets updated.

Sorry for the long and messy question but I am stuck bad any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

*fyi: I am using react-beautiful-dnd*

**EDIT**
Please check here: https://codesandbox.io/s/silent-haze-wvrv7

Comment: Where does this _Assigning values from Array 1 in Array 2_ happen?

Comment: @Chris the code above is all inside component
component {
{values assigning array}
{return function}
}

Comment: Can you show the full component code? That will make it a lot easier to detect any mistakes.

Comment: @Chris, sorry for late response. The Sandbox link is added. Please check. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your DragDrop component. Your `columns` state isn't updated when new `sendGlobalFLZ` is sent via props. This is because the `useState` only runs once for initializing the value and then only updates the value when `set[StateVar]` is used.

You can fix this by implemented `useEffect` and providing `sendGlobalFLZ` as a dependency. This will cause it to re-run and update your columns everytime it receives a new memory address for `sendGlobalFLZ`.

```
const [allItemsUUID] = useState(() => uuid());
const [columns, setColumns] = useState(() => ({
  [allItemsUUID]: {
    name: "All Items",
    items: sendGlobalFLZ
    // items: staticData
  },
  [uuid()]: {
    name: "Week 1",
    items: []
  },
  [uuid()]: {
    name: "Week 2",
    items: []
  },
  [uuid()]: {
    name: "Week 3",
    items: []
  },
  [uuid()]: {
    name: "Week 4",
    items: []
  },
  [uuid()]: {
    name: "Week 5",
    items: []
  }
}));

useEffect(() => {
  const updatedColumns = {
    ...columns,
    [allItemsUUID]: {
      ...columns[allItemsUUID],
      items: sendGlobalFLZ
    }
  };

  setColumns(updatedColumns);
}, [sendGlobalFLZ]);
```

[Full changes here](https://codesandbox.io/s/patient-thunder-i0sbt?file=/src/DragDrop.js)

Comment: Thank you, it works :) during me trying I was using useEffect to map column items which didn't worked obviously. Thanks again :)